# Provisioning profile expiration

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have face a problem that all my app in my iphone is not working from 22 dec 2009, when we open app in iphone the show a error of provisioning profile is expired but i check all my provisioning profile in iphone developer program portal they show all are active.

I can not find out that problem if any body know that problem help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Periodically you have to renew your provisions.  You might also have to renew your developer build keychain.  Maybe you have done that already, but, be sure to download the renewed provision files and drag them into Xcode again.  Even if the website is updated, your local system needs to be updated too.

Comment: I have renew my provisions and drag it to x code when we built app the same problem is done. Can this problem started due to website update

Comment: Sorry, I think I was not speaking clearly about an update on the website.  I meant that even if you have renewed your provisions, etc. on the iPhone Dev Center site, you have to download them and load them into Xcode.  I do *not* mean that a change to the iPhone Dev Center website itself, like a change in the developer license, would cause your provisions to no longer work.  Sorry for any confusion.  Unfortunately I don't have more ideas for you.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

One quick fix to deal with expired provisioning profiles (e.g. when you can not access the developer portal to renew) is to set the date and time of your iphone to some date in the past.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this problem before if **any** of the provisioning profiles on the device have expired or your own provisioning profile is close to expiring.

Try removing any expired profiles and/or refreshing your own profile.

Answer (score 0):

I once had two provisioning profiles for another App and one was expired and it effected the App I was working on (even though the provisioning profile was okay for the App I was working on). All I did was deleted the expired one and everything worked.